# Fluent programming - empty methods

Tags: c#, fluent, fluent-interface

I'm currently working on MVC controls that are using a fluent API for the construction.
I have no troubles with that for the moment.

But every method in my fluent API does take a parameter. According to that parameter, a property is set.

For Example:

```
var grid = GridFor<Model>(items).WithName("MyName").WithRowHeader("true");
```

But now I'm wondering how a fluent API does work when you have methods that doesn't take for a parameter.

For example:

```
var result = Model.Validate(x => x.Age).When().It().Is().Any().Number();
```

More in detail, I'm struggling with an approach like this:

```
string s = "Hello";
s.Validate().It().Is().String();
s.Validate().It().Is().No().String();
```

I'm having difficulties here on how the String method would know if it should validate the given object to see if it's a string or not.
I guess I need to pass the whole chain into it and based on the chain execute my logic?

Can someone provide me some guidance on how something like that should and can be accomplished?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: They're just methods.  They work just like any other method.

Comment: That I don't really know how that should be accomplished. It might be something trivial but I just don't see it.

Comment: I know those are methods, but I don't see how I should chain them on to eachother.

Comment: Maybe something like `myObject.reset().defaultInitialization().WithName("Hello")`

Comment: If the brackets are what's bugging you you could use [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: It's not what's bugging my, but to validate a simple property to be a a number with the syntax above, I'm struggling.

Comment: Each method returns some object that supports the other methods.  So using your example, `Validate` returns an instance of a class that has a `When` method which returns an instance of a class that has an `It` method, etc.

Comment: I know, but I don't see how I could validate my property which such a syntax. Perhaps each method takes the value of the property Age with him

Comment: If all the methods were members of the class that has the `Age` property, then you wouldn't need to pass the age in.  They could each operate on the property directly.  But validating that Age is a number doesn't seem like it would need more than a single method, so that example might not be the best.

Comment: One possible source of confusion is that `Validate` does not appear to validate anything, it is just a transformation. I would expect `validate` to be passed a delegate that evaluates to a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works a bit like this:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static Validation<T> Validate<T>(this T source)
    {
        return new Validation<T>(source);
    }
}

public class Validation<T>
{
    private readonly T valueToValidate;

    public Validation(T value)
    {
        valueToValidate = value;
    }

    public void Is<T>(T value)
    {
        if (!Object.Equals(valueToValidate, value))
            throw new Exception();
    }

    public NegativeValidation<T> Not()
    {
        return NegativeValidation(value);
    }
}

public class NegativeValidation<T>
{
    private readonly T valueToValidate;

    public NegativeValidation(T value)
    {
        valueToValidate = value;
    }

    public void Is<T>(T value)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(valueToValidate, value))
            throw new Exception();
    }

    public NegativeValidation<T> Not()
    {
        return Validation(value);
    }
}

string s = "Hello World";
s.Validate().Is("Hello World");
s.Validate().Not().Is("Hello World"); // exception
s.Validate().Not().Not().Is("Hello World");
```

Comment: Thanks, is already a bit clear, but in the imagination that I would like to use: s.Validate().Is().Any().String(); Then I'm lost on how this should be implemented. Because the methods Is() and Any() would not do anything on their own. But the last method (String()) must now it has been called by "Is().Any()" because it might also have been called by "Is().Not().Any()". Small difference in code, huge difference in validation. You mind to adapt the code to the thing I propose here? That would make a lot clear to me.

Comment: @Complexity Each of those methods would return a different class or interface, with references to the previous classes.

Comment: But that does mean that I need to pass my whole chain in it. Because Is() and Not() would return the same interface and finally in my method Any() I must know against which I should validate.

Comment: That is not "fluent" programming, but storing the "history" of previous method invocations somewhere inside the object, to build an expression that represents the validation model. While it can be done, it is complex and prone to breaking (if you forget to "reset" the restrictions), and all that you can do with it you can do with properly constructed methods.

Comment: I know but I was looking at Moq that does something simiar.

Comment: If you want to see how it really works for a validation framework then just take a look at an open source one.

Comment: @Complexity not exactly the syntax you want, but close.